# How to Print logs after some interval using Promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have used setTimeout inside promise method and expecting that it should print my logs one after one with some delay. I do see that logs are printing at the same time. this is what have tried.

```
function content(value) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(value);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function messages(value) {
  var abc = content(value);
  abc.then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
}

messages('hurray 1');
messages('hurray 2');
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way: Your promises are created one immediately after the other, and so the console log will only be offset not by the delay you've specified, but the delay in creating these promises. So these logs will appear to print at the same time.

To achieve your desired outcome, you would have to edit your code to **chain** these promises so each is created after the previous resolves:

```
function content(value){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(value);
      resolve(value);
    }, 2000);
  });
}


content('hurray 1').then(() => content("hurray 2")).then(() => content("hurray 3")); //& so on...
```

Now each of these get logged by the interval you have specified in `content()`. I used arrow functions for readability but feel free to substitute them with the old fashioned way if you wish.

Comment: I tried the given solution, but the thing is content method can be called from any place. So I can't chain it inside one then block. Could you please help with any alternate solution? The order of the content method call should be as given below

content('hurray 1');
content('hurray 2');
content('hurray 3');